# angular click function send two arguments

Tags: javascript, css, angular, typescript, sass

how I can send two arguments in this method?

`<tr *ngFor="let match of item.matches " (click)="openMatchContent(match,$event)"`

```
 openMatchContent(match: any,event:any) {}
```

this code gives me an error the error is  `Expected 2 arguments, but got 1.`

Comment: What kind of error? What about passing an arrow function?

Comment: I see that there is no problem with this code, the method expects Two arguments and you are already passed them. Try to restart the project or to restart the IDE, maybe it is something related to that.

Comment: The code looks fine.

Comment: I restarted the ide but there's still a problem

Comment: Can you please share full ts and html code along with console error?

Comment: He won't, as there will be no error @AbhishekPriyadarshi :D

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes IDE make problems with parametr $event, try to delete comma between 2 arguments.

Comment: thank you for answer but when i deleted the comma i got  syntax  error (